# Matrix-multiplication with RcppArmadillo: Why is it not faster?

Tags: r, rcpp, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to do some matrix-multiplication with RcppArmadillo. However, my code shows that **it doesn't become faster with RcppArmadillo**.

I'm using Windows_10_Pro with R 3.2.4, and RcppArmadillo 0.6.600.4.0

For example:

```
library(RcppArmadillo)
library(inline)

MCplus <- cxxfunction(signature(X_="numeric", Y_="numeric"),body ='
arma::mat X = Rcpp::as<arma::mat>(X_);
arma::mat Y = Rcpp::as<arma::mat>(Y_);
arma::mat ans = X * Y * X;
return(wrap(ans));
', plugin="RcppArmadillo")

A <- matrix(1:16000000,4000,4000)
C <- matrix(2:16000001,4000,4000)

R_M <- proc.time()
ans_R <- A%*%C%*%A # test with R
proc.time() - R_M

C_M <- proc.time()
ans_C <- MCplus(A,C) # test with RcppArmadillo
proc.time() - C_M
```

The R outputs:

```
user  system elapsed
106.75   0.24 106.98
```

And the RcppArmadillo outputs:

```
user  system elapsed
108.28   0.23 108.56
```

**Is there something can be improved?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is faster for me using `microbenchmark` I got a mean of 7.36 seconds for R and 5.67 seconds for your RcppArmadillo  solution.

Comment: The other issue here is that this involves two copies of your data: one when constructing the Armadillo matrices, and another when creating R objects from the multiplied results. You can potentially avoid this cost by using Armadillo's advanced constructors: see http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat for more information.

Comment: Good point, and we do get these essentially for free with Rcpp Attributes now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R itself farms this out to LAPACK/BLAS -- and so does code linked to R that calls via the LAPACK/BLAS.  So yes, both approaches will run the same code and differences are only due to the small overhead.

There are many tutorials out there that tell you how to change your LAPACK libraries. This depends of course on the operating system. Start maybe with the [R Installation and Administration](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html) manual and its appendices.

Comment: Thank you so much! Does it mean that it could be faster if I change my LAPACK libraries, and there are no big differences between two approaches with the new libraries?

Comment: Yes.  Eg Revolution Analytics never stops talking about how their R is "faster" when (essentially) all they is bundle the (known good) Intel MKL multithreaded BLAS.  You can get those too, or use OpenBLAS, or ...  Google around, it is widely discussed topic.

Comment: I'll try it out. Highly appreciate your help : )

Comment: My pleasure. Please feel free to now accept (click on tickmark) and/or upvote (click on uparrow) this answer if it suits you.